# Get error when using any openssl function about config file despite passing location to the function in PHP

Tags: php, openssl

I'm trying to create a key pair using PHP's openssl functions, but I keep getting the error:

```
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
```

despite passing it the config file location (it exists in that location, I checked):

```
$res = openssl_pkey_new( array('config' => '/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf' ));

//Print errors
while ($msg = openssl_error_string()) echo $msg . "d<br />\n";
```

and even creating a symlink in `/usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf` didn't fix the problem.

When I check `phpinfo()` it shows that SSL is enabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Cfreak Might be, but there's no answer there either! Not sure what's causing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issues and could get it working by following the steps found in above mentioned questions. Basically check these points:

- php openssl extension is enabled in your php.ini
- path to openssl.cnf (as seen in phpinfo() ) is valid and file exists
- replace cnf file with a working one from other sources (like your xampp if you have one or the one from your php/extra folder)

My problem (and yours too as it seems) was a invalid cnf file. Since I was unable to correct it, I had to get one from other sources. The one from openssl.org DID NOT WORK. I found a working one in my xampp/php/extra folder.

Comment: When I run `phpinfo()` it says ssl is enabled. If I run `sudo a2enmod ssl` it says it's already enabled. BUT there's no mention of openssl in `php.ini`! There's no mention of the path to openssl.cnf in `phpinfo()` but it says it's enabled and using version `OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009`. This seems to be because it's compiled into Linux versions: http://serverfault.com/questions/348613/openssl-extension-for-php-in-ubuntu I tried replacing the cnf file with other examples that people said worked but this did not fix it.

Comment: Yes, the extension is compiled in on some versions. But it's strange that you dont see the path to the cnf file. Should not matter though since you already tried to set it manually. Did you try to get another cnf file and try that one?

Comment: yes, I tried 4 different ones and nothing worked, but after running the `sudo a2enmod ssl` it suddenly seems to be working! I'm not convinced this will persist across restarts, but even though it said it was already enabled and nothing to do, it appears it DID do something and somehow enabled the cnf to work (for now)